# Dandelion List Listener Fails

Tags: linux, chmod, eclipse

I am trying to use lisp in linux but I can not get the listener to work.
Using Eclipse's menu, in help -> install new software, I installed the dandelion plugin but every time I try to run lisp code, like `(+ 1 2)`, something simple, I get the following errors:

```
Error in background evaluation
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Error initialising connection
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Starting eval server failed
Cannot run program "/home/michael/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.clisp.linux.x86_2.49.2/binary/environment_clisp_2.49.2": error=13, Permission denied
```

I have tried running the command

```
sudo chmod + /home/michael/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.clisp.linux.x86_2.49.2/binary/environment_clisp_2.49.2
```

Yet I see no output, the terminal just goes to the next new line. I am running a 64bit ubuntu version 14. I am pretty new to all this but I would like to use linux as my main OS as it is quite convenient for school. If anyone has ideas please let me know!

I went in and manually edited the files permission to allow anyone to read and write. I now only get the errors.

```
Error in background evaluation
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Error initialising connection
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Ideas?

Comment: Which listener are you refering to? And I assume that the help menu that you've cited is from Eclipse, right?

Comment: yes the eclipse help menu sorry

Answer (score 0):

This answer will get the SBCL listener working in eclipse in linux using the Dandelion plugin.

What I had to do was tell my computer to show hidden files and folders. Manually navigate to

```
/home/michael/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.sbcl.linux.x86_1.1.10/binary
```

Right click on the executable and edit the permissions to allow me all read and write access. I did the same for

```
/home/michael/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/de.defmacro.dandelion.env.clisp.linux.x86_2.49.2
```

I restarted eclipse, ran the SBCL[1.1.10] listener and tested `(+ 1 2)` I got the answer 3. I can not get the CLISP 2.49.2 listener working but just being able to develop in linux in lisp makes me quite happy